# Indexing into cell array

Tags: matlab, indexing, cell-array

Please, I need help from anyone. I have a cell array of many rows and two colums. Column two has elements of varying length. Some are one, two, three and four elements. I want to convert these elements in column two from cell to double using cell2mat and store the in a new variable. I have been encountering this error "Assignment has more non-singleton rhs dimensions than non-singleton subscripts". I have tried a lot times to work and resolve this problem but i have no solution. Can anyone help? My code can be seen below.

```
for i = 1:length(p)
     ps(i,:) = cell2mat(p{i,1}(1,2))
end
```

Comment: A matrix must have fixed length and width, if you have varying length in your second column, do you want to pad the columns with less elements with zeros?

Comment: Padding with zeros will not do anything to the end result.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the column range (explicitly) for the input data and MATLAB will automatically expand `ps` to accommodate your data appropriately (filling in empty cells with zeros);

```
for k = 1:numel(p)
    data = cell2mat(p{k,1}(1,2));
    ps(k, 1:numel(data)) = data;
end
```

Obviously this has some performance implications since you're changing the size of `ps` with every loop iteration.

If you wanted to, you could pre-allocate `ps` with something like this

```
allData = cellfun(@(x)cell2mat(x(1,2)), p(:,1), 'uniform', 0);
ps = zeros(numel(allData), max(cellfun(@numel, allData)));
```

Comment: I get this error "Index exceeds matrix dimensions" when run the data with the code above.

Comment: @K.Sante which line produces the error? It's modeled after the input you have provided, so it could be that the entries of `p` don't necessary have at least 1 row and 2 columns (as you assumed in your post)

Comment: this where the code produces error, data = cell2mat(P{k,1}(1,2));. Thank you.

Comment: @K.Sante if you remove the left side of the assignment in your original post does that even run as you wrote it?

Comment: @Suave, it does run from where there is only one element in each row, then the code breakdown when the number of elements increases to two or three. I checked that manually and realized that if the first row has two elements, the code will all rows with elements one or two and breakdown if the number of elements increase to three. It is then that I get this error "Assignment has more non-singleton rhs dimensions than non-singleton subscripts" .

Comment: @K.Sante No I'm asking that if you change the contents of the loop to **only** `cell2mat(p{i,1}(1,2))` (remove the assignment operation) does that run without error?

Comment: I am sorry about not reading your question well. This is the error message I get when I run only cell2mat(p{i,1}(1,2)) "Index exceeds matrix dimensions."

Comment: @K.Sante Ok that's what I thought. Basically the data isn't as you expect it to be. Once you figure out why that using the index (1,2) doesn't work, then plug the answer into my solution and it will work. If you can, figure out at which iteration that fails and post the contents of that cell element that it's trying to index.

Comment: thank you. But when I test it manually at the command prompt one row at time, it works.

Comment: @K.Sante Can you post some of the data into your question?

Comment: [] -1567.31851519380                                                                            [] [-1583.09443811795,-1627.48078127450]                                         [] [-1641.39957512475,-1551.59317385164]                                         [] [-1662.61817413549,-1556.54060908217]                                           this is just the away the data looks. The for column is empty and the second column has varying length.

Comment: @K.Sante post that in the **original** question. And clearly you're going to have issues if there are empty cells.